# How manipulate the individual points in a TPath?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'd like to change the coordinates of certain points inside a TPath. The `TPath.Data.Points` property, however, is read-only.

Is there a way to manipulate them directly without having to go through the `TPath.Data` string, make the changes there, and refresh the control?

I'm thinking animation and also elegance.

Maybe someone has already doctored out an alternative fashion, otherwise I'll just go the string route...

(talking XE2, btw. Don't know if this still is an issue in later versions)

Comment: Is it possible to use a class helper? I'm out of compiler at the moment, but this should expose the `SetPoint` procedure: `TPathDataHelper = class helper for TPathData
    property Points[index: Integer]: TPathPoint read GetPoint write SetPoint; default;
  end;`.

Comment: Actually, the first thing I tried was alter the TPathData class directly in the FMX.Types unit:
property Points[AIndex: Integer]: TPathPoint read GetPoint write SetPoint; default;
but setting the Points didn't change anything. Even a Repaint didn't show any changes. I was going through the source to find the reason, and thought of asking in here in the mean time.

Comment: Found it. Had to expose the UpdatePath method too, and execute an UpdatePath followed by a Repaint to update the TPath.
I'll formulate an answer using class helpers.

Comment: @Domus: Make a it a habit never to modify the default units that come with Delphi. Even if it contains clear bugs, it's better to work around them the way RU RD suggested.  Other code relies on it, and if you ever reinstall, update, or try to compile on another machine, you'll have to apply the same patches. If you've got many it's going to be a PITA. I mean it, don't do it.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick: Oh, don't worry, Wouter, I don't. I just do it during the "dicking about" phase, when I'm trying to find out how the class works and what can be altered. If all that dust has settled, the class goes back to its natural moronic state and either new descendent classes are created or class helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class helpers as follows:

```
TPathHelper = class helper for TPath
public
  procedure UpdPath;
end;

TPathDataHelper = class helper for TPathData
public
  procedure SetPoint(AIndex: Integer; PathPoint: TPathPoint);
end;

{ TPathHelper }

procedure TPathHelper.UpdPath;
begin
  UpdatePath
end;

{ TPathDataHelper }

procedure TPathDataHelper.SetPoint(AIndex: Integer; PathPoint: TPathPoint);
begin
  Self.FPathData[AIndex] := PathPoint;
  Self.FRecalcBounds := True
end;
```

To alter a point, do the following:

```
var pp: TPathPoint;
begin
  pp.Kind := TPathPointKind.ppMoveTo;
  pp.Point := PointF(Path1.Data.Points[0].Point.X + 10,Path1.Data.Points[0].Point.Y);
  Path1.Data.SetPoint(0,pp);
  Path1.UpdPath;
  Path1.Repaint;
```

Comment: At least in recently Delphi version (Tokio, Rio) `FPathData` is private so it should not be visible from `TPathDataHelper`. Does it compile in your Delphi version?

Comment: @Delmo I've given up trying to fight the "logic" or aiming for maximum efficiency, and resorted to rebuilding the entire path each time.